# Issue with parallel estimation of Transformer embeddings

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, huggingface-transformers, ray

I am attempting to compute BERT embeddings for a list of sentences using the Ray parallelization framework. The objective is to speed up this computation by running each sentence list (item contained in sentences_chunks below) parallelly by taking advantage of the multi-core CPU on my machine. Following is the code I am using for this purpose:

```
import ray 
from transformers.pipelines import pipeline 
import tensorflow as tf 
import pandas as pd 
import psutil 

num_cpus = psutil.cpu_count(logical=True)
pipe = pipeline(task = 'feature-extraction',
                tokenizer='distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english',
                model='distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english',
                framework='tf',
                batch_size=1,
                device=-1) 

def process_sentences(): 
   pipe_id = ray.put(pipe) 
   s_embeddings = ray.get([gen_sentence_embeddings.remote(pipe_id, chunk) for chunk in sentences_chunks]) # sentences_chunks is a list where each item is a list of sentences 
   

@ray.remote
def gen_sentence_embeddings(pipeline, sentences):
    try:
        input_ids = tf.constant(pipeline.tokenizer([str(sentence)[0:511] for sentence in sentences])['input_ids'])[None, :][0]
        s_embeddings = [pipeline.model(input_id).last_hidden_state[0][0].numpy() for input_id in input_ids]
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        
    s_embeddings = pd.DataFrame(s_embeddings).astype("float")

    return pipeline(s_embeddings) 

def main():
    ray.init(num_cpus=num_cpus, ignore_reinit_error=True)

    process_sentences()

    ray.shutdown()

main()
```

I get the following errors when running this code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/ray/_private/worker.py", line 687, in put_object
    serialized_value = self.get_serialization_context().serialize(value)
  File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/ray/_private/serialization.py", line 468, in serialize
    return self._serialize_to_msgpack(value)
  File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/ray/_private/serialization.py", line 447, in _serialize_to_msgpack
    metadata, python_objects
  File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/ray/_private/serialization.py", line 408, in _serialize_to_pickle5
    raise e
  File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/ray/_private/serialization.py", line 404, in _serialize_to_pickle5
    value, protocol=5, buffer_callback=writer.buffer_callback
  File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/ray/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py", line 88, in dumps
    cp.dump(obj)
  File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/ray/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py", line 733, in dump
    return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
TypeError: can't pickle weakref objects

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/ray/_private/worker.py", line 2597, in put
    object_ref = worker.put_object(value, owner_address=serialize_owner_address)
  File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/ray/_private/worker.py", line 696, in put_object
    raise TypeError(msg) from e
TypeError: Could not serialize the put value <transformers.pipelines.feature_extraction.FeatureExtractionPipeline object at 0x7f9b837efa90>:
================================================================================
Checking Serializability of <transformers.pipelines.feature_extraction.FeatureExtractionPipeline object at 0x7f9b837efa90>
================================================================================
!!! FAIL serialization: can't pickle weakref objects
    Serializing '_abc_impl' <_abc_data object at 0x7f9b801083c0>...
    !!! FAIL serialization: can't pickle _abc_data objects
    WARNING: Did not find non-serializable object in <_abc_data object at 0x7f9b801083c0>. This may be an oversight.
================================================================================
Variable: 

    FailTuple(_abc_impl [obj=<_abc_data object at 0x7f9b801083c0>, parent=<transformers.pipelines.feature_extraction.FeatureExtractionPipeline object at 0x7f9b837efa90>])

was found to be non-serializable. There may be multiple other undetected variables that were non-serializable. 
Consider either removing the instantiation/imports of these variables or moving the instantiation into the scope of the function/class. 
================================================================================
Check https://docs.ray.io/en/master/ray-core/objects/serialization.html#troubleshooting for more information.
If you have any suggestions on how to improve this error message, please reach out to the Ray developers on github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/
================================================================================
```

The problem seem to occur at ray.put(). Any help to resolve this error would be much appreciated.